# casting integer array to object array in java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am using JDK 1.6 but the second line in the following snippet gives a compile error in Eclipse:

```
long[] css = new long[]{1, 2, 3};
Object[] objs = Arrays.copyOf(ccs, ccs.length, Object[].class );
```

Error is:  The method copyOf(long[], int) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (long[], int, Class)

Casting is required for

```
org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions.in("PropertyName", objs );
```

Any ideas or recommended approach?

TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that in the java. `long` is a primitive type, and does because of that not extend `Object`. `Long`, which is a wrapper class for `long`, does and can be cast to an `Object`. To create a `Long[]` from a `long[]` you will need to go through every value of `long[]` and copy that to `Long[]`:

```
long[] primitiveLong;
Long[] wrappedLong = new Long[primitiveLong.length];
for (int i=0; i<primitiveLong.length; i++) {
    wrappedLong[i] = primitiveLong[i];
}
```

Then you can cast it to an array of `Object`:

```
Object[] objs = wrappedLong;
```

Or you can even make the wrappedLong of type `Object` directly so you don't need the casting.

Comment: +1 I believe that is the requirement for the copyOf method mentioned.

Comment: This is a copy not a cast.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a quick way to convert from long to Long ?  I am working with an API that provides long[] instead of Long[].

Comment: @Gili, how will I do a cast?  I surely cannot do (Long[])new long[]{1,2}

Comment: @KNji, the correct answer is: "What you are asking for is impossible in Java, however you can make a copy like this..."

Comment: @KNji, You can not cast from a primitive type to an Object. What you can do is go through every element of the long[] and copy it to a new Long[].

Answer (score 3):

Use Apache Commons' `ArrayUtils.toObject` which does exactly this.